# How to use php variable inside pdf ->page_script()?

Tags: php, dompdf

How to use PHP variable inside $pdf->page_script();
Here is my code

```
<?php
<script type="text/php">
$pdf->page_script(\'
    if ($PAGE_NUM >= 2) {$pdf->image($var,"jpg",25,500,0,0);
    }
  \');

</script>

?>
```

I am getting an error Syntax error in $var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline script is run via the [`eval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.eval.php) function and any variables declared in the global scope are only accessible via the `$GLOBALS` superglobal (`$GLOBALS['var']`) or by initializing them with the `global` keyword (`global $var`).

I should note that if you're using dompdf 0.6.x you no longer have to specify the image type. You also appear to have the parameters backwards. The method looks for image path, x, y, width, then height.

The following should work:

```
<?php
<script type="text/php">
  $pdf->page_script('
    if ($PAGE_NUM >= 2) {
      $pdf->image(' . $GLOBALS['var'] . ',0,0,25,500);
    }
  ');
</script>
?>
```

Minor note: Since you're creating a page script I concatenated the image path variable with the rest of the script string. You can include that variable reference as part of the script rather than concatenate, but then you're performing additional look-ups on the variable every time the script is run. Though I must admin this is a minor performance consideration in the grand scheme of where this is running.

Comment: THanks for ur reply BrianS. But i am getting an error like Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_STRING)

Comment: Its working fine now..Thank You So much...Now i need to apply some css for that image...u have any idea?

Comment: You'll have to go back to using HTML+CSS for that. The inline script works directly with the underlying PDF library. Unfortunately, that means finding a different way of keeping the image off page 1.